# Run time error in VBA code - excel

Tags: vba

I am facing `run time error 1004 object error` while running this code

```
lC4 = Cells(155, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Try explicitly referencing the sheet of interest

Comment: Something like ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(155, ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: Is the worksheet or workbook password locked?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using explicit sheet reference to ensure working with correct sheet and not implicit activesheet which may fail if workbook not in focus for example

Something like

```
ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(155, ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```